# Do desktop programs in Windows 8 get the benefit of touchscreen operations?

Tags: .net, winapi, windows-8

Do older Windows 7 or earlier programs get at least some of the benefits of touch screen operations on Windows 8 desktop. Will taps and finger hovers be activated in Windows 8. Can touchscreen APIs be used to update desktop Windows programs???

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The existing WM_GESTURE messages from Windows 7 still work on Windows 8.  In addition, desktop applications can take advantage of the unified input stack.  Check the [WM_POINTERUPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454929%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message for more info on how desktop applications can receive unified mouse, pointer and pen inputs.

Note that you need to call [RegisterPointerInputTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with your window handle to receive the unified pointer messages.